# Pandas: average over duplicate index values in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,3,1,2,3,4],
                   'b':[4,4,2,4,6,7,8,9]},
                   index = ['2010Q1', '2010Q1', '2010Q2', '2010Q2', '2010Q2',
                            '2010Q3', '2010Q3', '2010Q4'])

        a  b
2010Q1  0  4
2010Q1  1  4
2010Q2  2  2
2010Q2  3  4
2010Q2  1  6
2010Q3  2  7
2010Q3  3  8
2010Q4  4  9
```

Notice that each index value is duplicated. What I want is to return another DataFrame that average over the duplicated index rows and returns another DataFrame that has no duplicates.

e.g.

```
          a    b
2010Q1  0.5  4.0
2010Q2  2.0  4.0
2010Q3  2.5  7.5
2010Q4  4.0  9.0
```

I have an idea about how to grab the first or last duplicated row, but I dont know how to average over the duplicates.

e.g.

```
df[df.index.duplicated(keep = 'first')]
df[df.index.duplicated(keep = 'last')]
```

Comment: `df.groupby(df.index).mean()`?

Answer (score 1):

I think @user3483203's `groupby` approach is the most straightforward.  But one additional option is to use [`pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df.reset_index().pivot_table(columns=["index"]) # add .T to transpose dates to rows

index  2010Q1  2010Q2  2010Q3  2010Q4
a         0.5     2.0     2.5     4.0
b         4.0     4.0     7.5     9.0
```